# Intelligent way to autoref / label enumerations

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, automation

I want to automatically label and reference a enumeration of functional requirements.
The labeling works, but I can't reference the list items via `\ref{REQ1}` etc.

```
\begin{enumerate}[label*={\textbf{REQ\arabic*}}, ref={REQ}\arabic*]
    \item First requirement
    \item Second requirement
    \item Third requirement 
\end{enumerate}
```

Output should look like following (that's working already)

**REQ1** First requirement

**REQ2** Second requirement

**REQ3** Third requirement

---

Here's a SSCCE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[raiselinks=true,
                        bookmarks=true,
                        bookmarksopenlevel=1,
                        bookmarksopen=true,
                        bookmarksnumbered=true,
                        hyperindex=true,
                        plainpages=false,
                        pdfpagelabels=true,
                        pdfborder={0 0 0.5},
                        colorlinks=false,                       
                        linkbordercolor={0 0.61 0.50},   
                        citebordercolor={0 0.61 0.50}]{hyperref}  %{0.57 0.74 0.57}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label*={\textbf{REQ}\arabic*}, ref={REQ}\arabic*]
    \item First requirement
    \item Second requirement
    \item Third requirement 
\end{enumerate}

\dots
The capabiltiy of using magic is given to us by fulling the first requirement \ref{REQ1}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Technically, the labelling doesn't work, at least not on the code you've given! (You are missing something to separate `\textbf` from `REQ`.) Could you extend your code snippet into a small compilable `.tex` file, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`? It would make it easier to reproduce your issue on my machine, and work towards a solution.

Comment: It's not usually a good idea (or at least not what the system was designed for) to use automatic numbered labels for cross references. The whole idea of `\label{}` and `\ref{}` is that you use a _symbolic_ name and then if you decide to insert additional items, the number changes but the reference still works.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Was a copy&paste error... I changed it. I'm going to add a full code expample in a few minutes. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good Point. I don't think there will be change, all the requirements have been declared already, I just want to collect the ones I need to implement and define them in detail.

Comment: If you have two enumerated lists, how are you going to distinguish between items in the first and second list?

Comment: I simply don't. To be exact, I want a list with functional requirements and another with nonfunctional. ...I'm friend friend of generic programming, I'm just looking for a way to be less verbose :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the package `enumitem-zref`. Its [documentation's](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem-zref/enumitem-zref.pdf) first point is exactly, what you want.